# Index file of cloned project isnt showing in localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have cloned this github repository and i have it in my /var/www/html folder but when i go try to run the file in my browser i dont see anything

This is the link to the github repo I try to clone
https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend

But when I go to /var/www/html/pancakeswap-frontent/public

I only see an empty site in my browser.

How do i properly clone this prject?

I also tried all version of npm run, npm run start npm run-script even with sudo but i cant run this file
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried npm start?

Comment: how are your running file in browser? or what do you mean by **when i go try to run the file in my browser**.

Comment: yes i did try to run npm start in the public folder, in the src folder but i keep getting erros

Comment: i was trying to open the index file in my browser but this didnt work

Comment: @Bonfire I didnt run npm install prior to npm start

Comment: Opening a .js or .ts file in the browser won't work. Only HTML and PHP files can be run directly

Comment: Which file exactly did you try to open?

Comment: I just try to run the frontend repo- its a react app and i cant run it, i did npm install and than npm run in the src folder but i get a compile error